# How to have a swiss roll keep its shape

Tags: baking, cake, presentation

I made a bûche de noël this Christmas, using a rolling technique, like a swiss roll. I tried my best to get a good shape: I rolled the sponge sheet right out of the oven and let it cool down in the proper shape. When it was cool, I unrolled, smeared the filling onto it, and rolled it tightly. Then I packed it in permanent "baking paper", and placed two rubber bands on the two ends. Then I let it rest in the fridge (also to give the filling time to set, because it contained gelatine - but note that the filling was not all that liquid when smeared).

When I took it out the next day, the "log" had slumped, and was about twice as wide as tall. It looked more like a badly made stollen than like a tight cylinder. It was cohesive, in that it didn't try to unroll or break apart, it was just not round. The taste was good, but the presentation was disappointing.

What additional steps can I take to make sure that I get a nice, tight roll that keeps its shape in storage?

Comment: What did the cross section look like?  Did it look like the filling had squished, or the cake portion had compressed?

Comment: IME Swiss rolls always, always sag, in proportion to how much filling they contain. I suspect chilling in a couche-like pan with a semicircular cross section could help, but I haven’t seen such a thing.

Comment: @Joe the sponge did not compress, although it was a very airy one. It looked simply slumped. The filling layer was maybe half the thickness of the sponge layer, so while it was a clearly filled cake (as opposed to some cheap versions with only a thin jam glaze), it had enough sponge to hopefully hold the structure together.

Comment: I wonder if chilling the cake before it’s been filled will firm it up to prevent this… without making it too much of a pain to unroll to spread the filling

Answer (score 3):

Next time place the rolled swiss roll in a narrow container, as wide as the roll in its packaging, by preference with a round bottom. Otherwise fill the bottom corners of the container so that the roll is cushioned over its full length and can no way drop down in the corners.

And when plating up as a roll you might still want to add a cushion under the sides of the roll, so it can not break when cutting.